# App won't load on heroku, can't decipher heroku logs to tell what the error is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

[Update: I have a syntax error in my comment_update_job.rb file and I am troubleshooting that now] 
I am taking an online Rails course and my app has suddenly stopped working. Could someone please help point me in the right direction for deciphering the heroku logs?

Here is my comment_update.job.rb file

```
class CommentUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(comment, current_user)
    ProductChannel.broadcast_to(comment.product_id, comment: render_comment(comment, current_user), average_rating: comment.product.average_rating)
  end

private

  def render_comment(comment, current_user)
    CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment, current_user: current_user })
  end

end
```

Here is my heroku log:

```
2018-12-06T16:09:16.954955+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-12-06T16:09:16.954980+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.1 application starting in production
2018-12-06T16:09:16.954982+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-12-06T16:09:16.957071+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': /app/app/jobs/comment_update_job.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
2018-12-06T16:09:16.957089+00:00 app[web.1]: end
```

Comment: Is there anything helpful before that? Does this happen when making a request? Or, when loading the application?

Comment: I don't think so. When I go to the app it tells me it can't be loaded and tells me to look in heroku logs for the error

Comment: I thought there was typically some error information before the `Exiting` statement.

Comment: I added the top part of the code, I'm not able to fit the whole log. Is there something at the top that helps? Thanks

Comment: Please add `/app/app/jobs/comment_update_job.rb` to your question as that seems to be where you have a syntax error (see end of first line of the error message).

Comment: Updated with that code, thanks again

Comment: Is that the entire file? It's missing `end` and the end. BTW, I don't know why you took out the error message. It's useful and without it, other readers won't have important information.

Comment: It was, I added the other end and reposted here. I can add the error code back in, I was having trouble getting the logs to meet the character requirement and I wanted to get back to you asap.

Comment: That extra end fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Added as answer so you can accept/upvote for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you edited your question, you showed:

```
class CommentUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(comment, current_user)
    ProductChannel.broadcast_to(comment.product_id, comment: render_comment(comment, current_user), average_rating: comment.product.average_rating)
  end

  private

  def render_comment(comment, current_user)
    CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment, current_user: current_user })
  end
```

This is missing an `end`. It should be:

```
class CommentUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(comment, current_user)
    ProductChannel.broadcast_to(comment.product_id, comment: render_comment(comment, current_user), average_rating: comment.product.average_rating)
  end

  private

  def render_comment(comment, current_user)
    CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment, current_user: current_user })
  end

end
```

BTW, in my `config/environments/development.rb`, I like to set:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

This will cost you time on start up. But, it creates a closer match between your production and development environments and will typically cause errors to be thrown in development that would otherwise not be thrown until you're deploying to Heroku. IMO, the additional start up time in development is more than made up by saving the time of failed deployments on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this error, but I think it might be or a routing problem, or a redis database missing plug-in.

I suggest you to use PostgreSQL with heroku platform it very-well integrated and there is a free Hobbistic version that allow you to test and fully use your app for staging.

Look for ENV_VARIABLES in your heroku dashboard (like dev/production mode and other).

Hope that this thing could help you :)

Comment: I thought I was using Postgres, is there something that shows I'm not?